# How to digitally sign the xml documents using php?

Tags: php, xml, digital-signature

I've to add digital signatures to a xml document and recreate them..

How can i do this? I'm using simplexml to create xml documents. These digital signatures will be uploaded by users as either .pfx or .p12 file.

Is there any pre-defined classes for doing this?

If there is none, at least i want to know what details has to be added to a signed xml documents and how to get them from digital signature files?

Comment: see if this is what you are looking for: [What do I need to know about XML Signatures to get SAML working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937297/what-do-i-need-to-know-about-xml-signatures-to-get-saml-working)

Comment: Why this question is marked for close? I searched SO for same questions before and nothing seems to be there. Even if some questions are related to xml, they don't have info about digital signing. So only i posted a new question..

Comment: @gordan : That gave me the structure of digital signature portion in the xml but it doesn't have any info about how to read info from signature files and also to add them.. Anyway it helped me to get the standard structure.. :)

Comment: @kvijay isn't that SAML stuff what you are looking for?

Comment: @gordan: I Just need to attach the signature details along with the simple xml document to authorize it.. Will SAML do that?

Comment: @kvijay it's spelled Gordon. If you write Gordan, I dont get noticed. I dont know if it can do that, check out http://simplesamlphp.org and tell us :)

Comment: @gordon Sorry , i didn't noticed the spelling. :)

Comment: @kvijay did SimpleSamlPhP solve your problem?